# Python file works in Pycharm but not in termial

Tags: python, terminal, pycharm, out-of-memory

I am running a python file in pycharm and there is no problem, but when I want to run it in the terminal, I get the error: `tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InternalError: CUDA runtime implicit initialization on GPU:0 failed. Status: out of memory`

Why does the same script work in pycharm but not in the terminal?

Comment: Please remove the Linux tag. All `Linux` questions must be related to programming; those that aren't will be closed. Use this tag only if your question relates to programming using Linux APIs or Linux-specific behavior, not just because you happen to run your code on Linux.

Answer (score 1):

Actually it works on pycharm is the same as it works on terminal, what I mean is, pycharm indirectly uses their inbuilt terminal as I've noticed, so my guess is that you might have a module error, because all the modules you install in pycharm are just stored in a virtual environment, and not in the actual environment.

Comment: Thank you, is there a way to see which modules are missing with respect to the virtual environment?

Comment: Please try and run `pip freeze` in PyCharm's terminal and normal terminal. This should show the installed modules with their versions. Compare if any of them is missing or different.

Comment: Yes! @JesusM. you can type this following code in pycharm, save it, and run it.

`import os;os.system('pip list`);

Comment: Also if you find this answer correct with respect to your question. Please be sure to tick it as a 'Accepted Answer' by clicking on the check-mark

Comment: I have run that code in pycharm, then made `pip list` in the terminal, and then compare the two results, but they are the same.

Comment: I see so that mean that it isn't any models error. And also I havent worked with tensorflow yet so I dont know much 'bout it

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve the problem, for everyone who have the same problem, I add at the beggining:

```
import os
os.environ['TF_FORCE_GPU_ALLOW_GROWTH'] = 'true'
import tensorflow as tf
physical_devices = tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU')
for device in physical_devices:
    tf.config.experimental.set_memory_growth(device, True)
```

And now it works perfectly

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).